# Import dll in different QT versions

Tags: dll, plugins, qml, qt-creator

I was using an external dll file in my project and now upgraded my QT version from Qt5.5.1 to 5.10.1.
Now I have issues using a dll File.

- Is there a chance to reuse the same dll in newer QT-Versions?
- Are dll files created for specific QT versions?

I have run qmlplugindump.exe from Qt5.5.1 binaries and from Qt5.10.1 binaries:

`qmlplugindump com.IO.Plugin 1.0 C:\...\com\IO\Plugin`

Qt5.5.1: [WORKS]

```
import QtQuick.tooling 1.2

// This file describes the plugin-supplied types contained in the library.
// It is used for QML tooling purposes only.
//
// This file was auto-generated by:
// 'qmlplugindump com.IO.Plugin 1.0 C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\mingw53_32\qml\com\IO\Plugin'

Module {
    dependencies: []
    Component {
... }
```

Qt5.10.1: [DOES NOT WORK]

```
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/mingw53_32/qml/com/IO/Plugin/qmldir: plugin cannot be loaded for module "": Cannot load library C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\mingw53_32\qml\com\IO\Plugin\IOPlugin.dll: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Qt5.7.0: [DOES NOT WORK EITHER (Added to question 27-Aug-2018)]

```
This plugin does not support createPlatformOpenGLContext!
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/mingw53_32/qml/com/IO/Plugin/typelist.qml:2:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "com.IO.Plugin": Cannot load library C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\qml\com\IO\Plugin\IOPlugin.dll: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Creating a plugins.qmltypes file with Qt5.5.1-qmlplugindump leads to have Qt5.10.1 recognizing the plugin without underlining it red and showing the QML-Component as known but it still creates the following error when compiling the project:

```
plugin cannot be loaded for module "com.IO.Plugin": Die Bibliothek C:\...\release\com\IO\Plugin\IOPlugin.dll kann nicht geladen werden: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. [Translated: can not be loaded: The modul can not be found]
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
```

Comment: Are you sure the module exists? According to the message Qt just can't find the specified module.

Comment: I am using exactly the same command with qmlplugindump.exe (Qt5.5.1 & 5.10.1) therefore it is searching in the same directory for the same files.